# Nested UIStackViews inside a UIScrollView: Not filling width of container?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, uistackview

I'm trying to programmatically create a 3x33 grid of `UIButton`s using nested `UIStackView`s inside a `UIScrollView`. The outer `UIStackView` has a vertical axis, while the inner `UIStackView`s have horizontal axes and `distribution = .fillEqually`.

If I don't have the enclosing `UIScrollView`, the buttons properly fill the width of the screen. *With* the scroll view, however, the buttons fill only half the width of the screen.

Here is a code example. In IB, `ViewController`'s `view` property has been set to a `UIScrollView` instance.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var stackView: UIStackView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "No Filling :("

    stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 5
    view.addSubview(stackView)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[stackView]-|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView!]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[stackView]|", options: .alignAllCenterY, metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView!]))

    for _ in 1...33 {
      let hView = UIStackView()
      hView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      hView.axis = .horizontal
      hView.distribution = .fillEqually
      hView.spacing = 5

      stackView.addArrangedSubview(hView)
      stackView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[hView]|", options: .alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["hView": hView]))

      for i in 1...3 {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
        hView.addArrangedSubview(button)

        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 7
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your scrollView's content width to be the width of the scrollView itself so that it fills the screen and scrolls vertically.

In order to do that, you need to establish the width of the scrollView's content.  Right now, it is getting its width from the intrinsic size of the three buttons.

You need to add a constraint that explicitly makes the scrollView's content (the stackView + left and right offsets) equal to the width of the scrollView:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "H:|-20-[stackView]-20-|", options: .alignAllCenterX,
    metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView!]))

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
    withVisualFormat: "V:|[stackView]|", options: .alignAllCenterY,
    metrics: nil, views: ["stackView": stackView!]))

stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
```

**Note:** The adjustment `constant` `-40` is the sum of the left and right offsets (`20` each).  In order for the scrollView to not scroll horizontally: `stackView.width + 20 + 20 == scrollView.width`, or equivalently, `stackView.width == scrollView.width - 40` which is what the constraint specifies.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I realize I must be misunderstanding `NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat:options:metrics:views)`. My previous understanding was that the visual format `H:|-[stackView]-|` would take care of its leading, trailing, and width anchors, setting them based on the superview’s own anchors (in this case the scroll view). Why doesn’t it also set the width anchor?

Comment: That only creates the leading and trailing constraints.

Comment: You can test that by adding `.count` to that command and observing that only 2 constraints are created.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again.